# Merge two very similar methods

Tags: java, jsf

I have this theoretical situation:

a **form** with

- **2 inputs** [attributes `attr1`, `attr2` of object `item`] **

  ```
  <h:inputText id="attr1" value="#{bean.item.attr1}"/> 
  <h:inputText id="attr2" value="#{bean.item.attr2}"/>
  ```
- **2 submit buttons** [searching by `attr1`, `attr2` in dtb] in foo.xhtml:

  ```
  <h:commandButton id="search1" action="#{bean.search1}" /> 
  <h:commandButton id="search2" action="#{bean.search2}" />
  ```

and **two very similar methods** in bean.java:

```
public void search1(){
    try 
    {
      session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
      criteria.add(Restrictions.like("attr1", item.getAttr1()));
      dataList = criteria.list();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {...}
  }

  public void search2(){
    try 
    {
      session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
      criteria.add(Restrictions.like("attr2", item.getAttr2()));
      dataList = criteria.list();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {...}
  }
```

Is there some way to merge these two methods to one?

**UPDATE:** and also merge action of commandButtons?

**SOLUTION:**

```
private void search(String field, String value)
action="#{bean.search('attr2', bean.item.attr1)}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass what's different as a parameter:

```
public void search(String param, Attr attr){
    try 
    {
      session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
      criteria.add(Restrictions.like(param, attr));
      dataList = criteria.list();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {...}
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Bozho, it was a wrong question, i should ask to merge even the actions in command button, something like `action="#{bean.search(bean.item.attr1, "aatr2")}"` :-)

Comment: mein gott, you're right, but with 'attr2' instead of "attr2"... thank you and sorry :)

Comment: Passing method arguments in EL is not JSF2 specific. It's EL 2.2 specific. It will even work for JSF 1.x as long as you're using EL 2.2.

Comment: yup - if you deploy a JSF 1.2 app in a container supporting EL 2.2 (Tomcat 7 for example), it will work

Answer (score 2):

Sure: look for what's the same, and what's different. You don't provide enough info to know whether or not this is possible:

```
public void search(String sAttr, T attr) {
    try {
        session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like(sAttr, attr));
        dataList = criteria.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {...}
}
```

If the attribute types aren't the same, it's a bit more irritating, and the joy that is Java rears its ugly head.

At some point you'll end up with a method that takes a `Criteria` and you either create those on-the-fly and pass them in to something that wraps up the try/catch and list, or you end up creating an interface and passing an implementation in to the same.

On a side note, IMO creating side-effect dependencies like setting `dataList` inside a search method will eventually lead to tears: consider returning the list from the method instead, even if you just set it to a property to get passed along to whatever uses it.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a third method and call it from within those methods:

```
private void doSearch(String field, String value) {
  session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.like(field, value));
  dataList = criteria.list();
}

public void search1() {
  doSearch("attr1", item.getAttr1());
}

public void search2() {
  doSearch("attr2", item.getAttr2());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Crozin, it works, but my question was wrong, I should ask to merge even the actions (see my answer to bozho please) :-/